# Restore Ambiance Gtk theme for Unity Desktop

Tags: unity, 11.04, gtk, themes

I am using Ubuntu 11.4 alpha3 for testing. I see that some applications have been removed like Appearance where we play with theme preferences.

How can I change themes in Unity? What interface do I use?

During the upgrade process my default Ambiance theme got corrupted.

Window decoration are fine but GUI widget (e.g boxes, button, scrollbars) now have Windows9xish look.

How can I restore my default Ambiance theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit `<super>` (aka the "windows key") and start typing "appearance" (or what ever it is called in your locale). You should find the old Appearance app for tweaking your theme.

Or you can right click on your desktop and select "Change Desktop Background" and select the theme tab to switch themes.